# APPIRATER setsignificantevent iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, appirater

Basically I am using appirator to let user for rating my app only when the user does some signification events.Here is it how I have done it.
1.Have set the following in my app delegate

```
[Appirater setAppId:jumpStart.appID];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:3];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

2.Now in one of my view controller there is a button which tells the user to provide feedback.If the user has hit the button,then on its action I have provided the following.

```
[Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES];
```

Now,if the user has hit the button3 times then the Rating popup should appear.But,this is not happening.Can anybody let me know where is it that I am going wrong.Do I need to do something else apart from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use this.

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"122133"];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:3];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to days until prompt and uses until prompt too zeros:

```
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:0];
```

Otherwise defaults values are too big for your case (30 days and 20 uses).

Comment: How to reset the significantcount if the user hits "remind me later". ?

Comment: It seems there is no options to reset significant event count explicitly.

Comment: so in that case when will the Rating appear next if the user hits "Remind Later"?will that be after next 3 hits or will it be random?

Comment: Prompt will appear after set period (by default 1 day), when next time user will do this significant event.

Comment: @AleksejsMjaliks  Suppose user clicked on the rate this app button but didn't gave rating to app. In that case alert will show again or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could have triggered some events during testing, you would need to explicitly reset them before trying again.

While Appirator didn't provide the methods to reset, you could reset by setting `NSUserDefaults` directly e.g.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"kAppiraterDeclinedToRate"];
```

Other keys to reset are `kAppiraterReminderRequestDate` and `kAppiraterSignificantEventCount`. You can find all the keys in Appirator.m.